# 500 error when sending emails on deployed rails 4 app. How do I see whats causing this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-cloud-platform

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this problem to findout what is going wrong.

When my deployed app is required to send an email it loads for a while then gives a 500 error. It sends the email fine in development and if I run the app in production on my local machine it also sends the emails fine so I cant reproduce it on my local machine and look at the logs. If I just deployed an update or fix then it will send the emails fine in the deployed version sometimes, but for the few times it works it stops working shortly after.

I'm using google cloud platform to host the app but can find a way to see what is causing the emails to not be sent and give me the 500 error. the GCP logs are useless and just say there was a 500 error at x time with no indication in what caused it.

How can I troubleshoot this problem or maybe what could be causing this?

Comment: you can check production log as well

Comment: the `delayed_jobs` table has a few attributes that are handy to troubleshoot like: `handler` , `attempts` and `last_error` .

Comment: Can you ssh into the server, run `rails c` and test sending emails that way?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow narrowed it down to be a firewall problem from my google cloud instance. By default they block port 465 (the port I was using to send emails).